# Two metal I Beams are not spliced

Tags: basement, beam, steel, column

We viewed a home that had steel I Beams. 2 of them were end to end over a support beam but were not spliced, they were only attached to the top of the pillar via 2 bolts per beam.

Very similar to this but steel rather than wood: https://www.familyhandyman.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/FH17ONO_582_20_001.jpg?resize=768,768

There was one odd thing I noticed in which it appeared that the beams were coming apart a forming some what of a V gap directly over the support beam.

Is this cause for concern? It seems like the beams could've been "spliced" together to keep them horizontally aligned.

I only raise this issue because the floor directly above was bowing in this exact spot directly over the support beam on the 1st floor, as was the 2nd story. The 2nd story also had a door which did not close straight in the frame because of the bowing of the floor.

Worried that maybe the V shape is expanding and soon the far ends of both beams may be sinking.

Comment: The beams just need good mounting on pillar.  Either the pillar was made too high or raising, or the ends are too low or sinking.  Does sound like a house to walk away from, till an engineer(not an inspector or Joe down the street) gives a cheap fix.

Comment: Is the wide part of the V gap forming between the bottom ends of the beams or the top ends? Wider at the bottom would imply that the support post is sinking.

Comment: @MichaelKaras it is wide at top, and narrower at the bottom. As crip659 said, I could see this v shape coming up if the support was pushing up, or if both ends are sinking down

Comment: Yes that is correct.